# HTML: How to keep spans with padding and borders from overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I have multiple spans with padding and borders one right after another that I want to wrap as the window dictates. But when they wrap, they overlap. Any way to keep them from overlapping without using a table? (Note: they only overlap vertically. horizontally they are fine)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `display:block`

`<span>` is `display:inline` by default, so the borders and padding you added aren't actually affecting it's size. You're seeing the overlap because the width of the border/padding is larger than the `line-height`

You may need `float:left` as well, or you can try `display:inline-block` instead.

More info on `display`: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: I would suggest changing this answer to highlight `display: inline-block;` first (and downplaying `float: left;`).